# Jquery on click do double tap

Tags: jquery, double, tap

Is there way to imitate double tap effect?

I mean:

I got smth like that:

```
$("#tap").click(function(event) {


});
```

And it should work like that, If you click on that ID it should imitate(not detect) doubletap effect.

EDIT:
Thanks for help, A bit of explainations:

I have default wordpress gallery ue-gallery.

It works fine in desktop but in mobile devices if I want to zoom gallery or zoomout it I have to double tap it(phones,tablets). I would like to add Close button (which I did) with id="tap". And that button should do simillar job as that double tap.

So I think doubletap and doubleclick are 2 diffrents things, also I found doubletap detector and triggered it:

https://gist.github.com/attenzione/7098476

$("#tap").click(function(event) { $(#gallery).trigger('doubletap') });
But it doesn't really work. So maybe should I try with full view mode. Do you know how to trigger it ? In few words it should work like that ;):

I click button "close" and it should trigger full view mode, so it would be like doubletap.

Thanks for help guys

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? It sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right .

> Trigger like this

```
$("#target").click(function() { 
    $(this).dblclick(); 
});

$( "#target" ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "Double Click !!" );
});
```

Checkout this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/advs1471/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : what does that mean ? its like `do something` on `double click` ..Is that OP wants? Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : ohk thanks so  so much sir ,, I edited the code